# How do I detect payments using PayPal v2 and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm developing a server that will detect PayPal payments to a specific PayPal account.
I've started looking into the PayPal SDK and got lost... I saw that V1 is deprecated, so I probably should use V2.

The only thing that I need is that PayPal will call my server webhook once the account receives money.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing that I need is that PayPal will call my server webhook

Don't do that. Use a proper server integration.

You need two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

The best approval flow for the customer to go through is: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , as your site stays loaded in the background, and it does not redirect away from your page.

---

When your capture transaction API call runs successfully and completes the order, you will have an immediate response with a payment object and transaction details. Thus, there is no need for the extra asynchronous step of waiting for a separate webhook call (which is prone to errors or exceptions), and your integration will be more robust.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, the PayPal account is a personal account and the payments are not "orders" these are only money transfers

Comment: It may not be possible for a personal account to create a REST API app with a client ID and secret to register for webhook events, at https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Comment: You can process payments for another account using the 'payee' object: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/ -- but of course, this will not help you if the payments are being sent to the PayPal account through arbitrary means

Comment: Anyway, upgrading from a Personal to a Business account is free and can usually be done seamlessly, depending on the country involved